# How can I store a spanned string in sqlite?

Tags: android, string, sqlite, mobile, spannable

In Android, I have an application that handles multiple rich format text fields. I get the description of the text from an xml and create it as an spannable string builder, adding each run and styling it.

Is there a way to store this on sqlite that doesn't imply storing the whole XML describing the paragraph?

I know it can be done in iOS but I haven't found a way for Android.

Thanks in advance for any answers or tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to store this on sqlite that doesn't imply storing the whole XML describing the paragraph?

I do not know what "the whole XML describing the paragraph" is. You can:

- Use `Html.toHtml()` to generate HTML from a `Spannable`, or
- Roll your own code to convert a `Spannable` into something that can be stored as a string or byte array

Comment: while converting spanned text with images <img src = "null"> why image source is null?